# What do they mean by lower envelope of parabolas?

Tags: conic-sections, envelope

I'm studying an algorithm on distance transforms and there's a part which confuses me.

> Let $G = \{0, . . . , n − 1\}$ be a one dimensional grid, and $f :G →R$ an arbitrary function on the
> grid. The squared Euclidean (or quadratic) one-dimensional distance transform of f defined
> by equation (1) is given by: $Df (p) = \displaystyle{\min
> _{q∈G}}
> ((p − q)^
> 2 + f(q))$.

> Note that for each point q ∈ G there is a constraint that the distance transform of f be
> bounded by a parabola rooted at (q, f(q)). In fact the distance transform is defined by the
> **lower envelope of these parabolas**, as shown in Figure 1. The value of the distance transform
> at p is simply the height of the lower envelope at that point.

What do they mean by **the lower envelope of some parabolas**? You can see "Figure 1", which they mention, below. Apparently, it seems envelopes are a term I just haven't heard of. Reading the definition didn't really help me and I'm not sure they refer to these envelopes in the paper.

[image]

Comment: Look up "envelope of a family of curves". It is a general concept. https://www.math24.net/envelope-family-curves

Comment: @DavidK As I said I looked it up  and the definition didn't help. I can see the parabola as an envelope of some curves. But I can't imagine an envelope of some parabolas. Maybe I haven't quite understood it yet. I'm still studying it but I'm somehow feeling it is not connected to the paper. I'm sure you know better and I'd like to know. Does the "lower" envelope make sense to you? Is there a "picture" that comes to your mind?

Comment: *"The 'Figure 1' which is mentioned doesn't help by the way."* Please include it, anyway. What doesn't help you might help others. And, after all, the question's author seems to think it's relevant.

Comment: OK, I see the problem with applying the usual definition here: $G$ is a finite set generating a finite number of parabolas.

Comment: @Blue Fair enough. I added the image.

Comment: @DavidK Maybe they are referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_envelope ?

Comment: Yes, that fits. I usually just call this the "minimum".

Comment: The lower envelope is "what you see if you're on the x-axis looking up," imagining that the curves obscure your vision. There are several ways to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the formal definition of the given distance transform,
$$ Df (p) = {\min_{q∈G}} ((p − q)^2 + f(q)), $$
it should be evident that the graph of $Df$ consists of portions of some of
the parabolas in Figure 1.
Not all of the parabolas contributed to the graph of $Df$;
for example, graph of $Df$ does not come anywhere near the parabola with vertex $(1,f(1))$.
But the graph of $Df$ consists of the portion of the parabola $\gamma_0$ with vertex
$(0,f(0))$ to the left of the intersection of $\gamma_0$ with the parabola $\gamma_2$
with vertex $(2,f(2)),$
and then a portion of the parabola $\gamma_2$ from that intersection
to whatever parabola $\gamma_2$ next intersects.

So we get a piecewise parabolic curve with a cusp in each place along the graph where the arcs of different parabolas intersect.

Figure 1 could have been improved by tracing parts of $Df.$

Answer (score 1):

An envelope of a family of parabolas is a curve that is tangent to each member at some point. These points of tangency together form the envelope. And lower envelope is the envelope determined by the pointwise minimum (geometrically, the "lowermost point" and hence the name) of the parabolas.

Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)), [this](https://www.math24.net/envelope-family-curves) [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_envelope) and [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F3%2F31%2FSignal_envelopes.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEnvelope_(waves)&tbnid=FF4w8nn1KLt04M&vet=12ahUKEwii0vyRnazyAhWfrmMGHZhKB0UQMygCegUIARCtAQ..i&docid=6MMsCaXDLt9O1M&w=602&h=378&q=lower%20envelope&ved=2ahUKEwii0vyRnazyAhWfrmMGHZhKB0UQMygCegUIARCtAQ) for more.

Comment: The image in the second link was very helpful. The parabolas placement helped in finding /imagining that envelope though. In the image I uploaded I found it very difficult to imagine such a curve. Do you understand what they mean by "lower" envelope?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas Lower envelope is the envelope determined by the pointwise minimum (geometrically, the "lowermost point" and hence the name) of the parabolas.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas Please check the edit. Since you love pictures, the last "this" contains another great picture to build your intuition on.

Comment: There are at least three different kinds of "envelope" illustrated in the links. The last link seems to be about amplitude modulation, which is quite different from what we need here. The link for "lower envelope" seems to be the right one.